# Facebook Event API, users does not receive notifications

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-events

After i invite friend via app (JS api) they don't have any way to accept invitation (they don't have notifications, or notification disappear directly on hover). So they are being invited, but don't even know about that.

Here is how i invite friend to event:

```
FB.api('/EVENT_ID/invited?users=USER_ID', 'POST', function(response){console.log(response);});
```

Comment: Can you show us the response of the request?

Comment: response is "true", means user is invited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request should look like that:

```
FB.api(
    '/707089732635823/invited',
    'POST',
    {
        access_token: FB.getAccessToken(),
        users: '100007028615075'
    },
    function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
)
```